# Bind a new terminal to rich console

Tags: python-3.x, linux, rich

I'm using `rich` library for formatting a live console window in Linux to show the progress of some tasks.
I want to start a new terminal from within Python, and provide that context to `rich` somehow so it can update the provided console. Of course, if I run the Python file from a terminal, the current terminal context is passed by default, and the layout is rendered right there. But since this "GUI" needs to run as a service, how can I achieve the same?

So far I've been starting a new terminal and then running my script, but this makes me lose so much control over the GUI application. Here is the command I'm using via systemd service

```
gnome-terminal --window --maximize -- sudo bash -c 'export PYTHONPATH="<path to project>" && /usr/bin/python3 -m station_gui.station_gui'
```

Comment: Curious: what kind of control do you lose? Overall, your approach seems correct: start the terminal, and start the application as (part of its) command line option(s).

Comment: @9769953 For example I cannot know when the other terminal was closed. Or if someone restarts the systemd services, then this `station_gui` service will start again and create another instance of the terminal.

Comment: I think partly, these are out of your hands: closing the terminal looks similar to the app as shutting down the computer. Restarting  systemd means you'll have to handle that in systemd; other apps must be doing the same (e.g., some apps just shut down and start up again when systemd is restarted).

Comment: But the two examples you describe, are gui desktop related, and I think therein lies your problem: you're using a console-only library/application, and then want to apply that to a graphical desktop. That is obviously not going to work, as that was never the intention: rich just about knows about the terminal, but it certainly won't know about the desktop & graphical interface it is being used in; in fact, it likely doesn't (and shouldn't) care.